# Error while passing parameters to UDA from nzplsql in netezza

Tags: postgresql, netezza

- I have a table test, which have columns listed as x0,x1,x2,x3
- I have an UDA which takes in two columns as arguments and does some computation
- I am trying to call the UDA from my nzplsq
- when I directly call UDA like:

  ```
  create table newtable as select ncorrFactor(x0,x2) from test;
  ```

It works

but when I try to do this:

```
p varchar;
p := X || 0 || '';

create table newtable as select ncorrFactor(p,x2) from test;
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  pg_atoi: error in "x0": can't parse "x0"
```

What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first snippet is a store procedure written in NZPLSQL for p to be treated as 'X0' you need to build your query dynamically and use "execute immediate" on that query.

eg:

```
declare
query varchar;
begin
 query:='create table newtable as select ncorrFactor('|| 0 ||',x2) from test';
 execute immediate query;
end;
```